# Links in footer are broken on insights.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, insights

The "Questions", "Jobs", "Documentation", and "Help" links in the Stack Overflow footer use relative URLs without a domain, so go to the wrong domain (**insights.stackoverflow.com**).  The resulting page is a 404.

[image: Screenshot of footer]

[image: Screenshot of code]

[image: Screenshot of error]

BTW, Insights is awesome :)

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. I've added it to our bug backlog for review after the holiday weekend.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been fixed. Footer links on [insights.stackoverflow.com](https://insights.stackoverflow.com) should now all point to the right place.